# Angular Slick carousel slides stacked up in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, slick.js

I'm using Angularjs slick carousel control in our application's home page. It may work some times, but most of time it is failing. I have given the option to show 3 slides at a time and have around 34 slides. Now, when I load the page, the slides are getting stacked up one over the other. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

```
<slick responsive="breakpoints" dots ="false" infinite ="true" autoplay ="true" speed="500" slides-to-show= "4" slides-to-scroll="4" class="slickContainer">
     <ul class="slider responsive" ng-repeat="item in slides">
        <li>
            <a ng-click="gotoContentPage(item.ContentId, item.ChapterId)"><span>{{item.ContentId}}</span>{{item.ContentCaption}}</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
    </slick>
```

I'm not getting any errors in console too. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It will work if we resize the browser window! Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to this problem. I thought of posting it here which may help someone with similar issue in future.
Immediately after binding the data, I have refreshed the slider which has solved my issue. The code snippet for that is as follows.

```
$('.slickContainer').slick('refresh');
```